# Do $4$ consecutive positive integers with square totient-value exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

$N=512$ is an example for a positive integer $N$, such that the totient values of $N$ , $N+1$ , $N+2$ are all perfect squares.

> Does a positive integer $N$ exist , such that the totient values of $N,N+1,N+2,N+3$ are all perfect squares ? In other words, can $4$ consecutive positive integers have square totient-values ?

Upto $N\le 10^8$, no such number exists.

Comment: The totient is closely linked to prime factorisations, and consecutive numbers have almost no connection between their prime decompositions at all (apart from the immediately obvious). Seeing as an example doesn't present itself immediately, I'd say this is probably not an easy question to answer. It's a cool problem, though.

Comment: No example upto $10^9$

Comment: Upto $3\cdot 10^9$, only the numbers $$N=512$$ and $$N=55384575$$ have the propery that $\varphi(N),\varphi(N+1),\varphi(N+2)$ are perfect squares, perhaps an easier task is to find another such triple.